# ELF Binary: why symbol value is different from actual symbol address?

Tags: arm, elf, disassembly, thumb

Here is the situation. I am investigating ARM binary files. When using `objdump -T` to see the dynamic symbol table, the output shows me (excerpt from a real case):

```
DYNAMIC SYMBOL TABLE:
00000000    DF  *UND*  00000000  __cxa_finalenter
....
00002055 g  DF  .text  00000060   SomeFunction
...
0000818c g  DF  .text  00000008   _Unwind_GetTextReleaseBase
....
```

And disassembly of the symbols gives the following (`objdump -d`):

```
    ...
00002054 <SomeFunction>:
    2054:   b5f7        push    {r0, r1, r2, r4, r5, r6, r7, lr}
    2056:   1c04        adds    r4, r0, #0
    2058:   4815        ldr r0, [pc, #84]   
    ...
0000818c <_Unwind_GetTextRelBase>:
    818c:   e92d4008    push    {r3, lr}
    8190:   ebffe79c    bl  2008 <abort@plt>
```

My question is, as you can see the value specified in the dynamic symbol table for `SomeFunction` is 0x2055 but the actual disassembly starts at 0x2054. However, for `_Unwind_GetTextRelBase`, the assembly starts at the address specified in the symbol table. What is the logic behind this and how can I programmatically identify the right beginning address?

Comment: Essentially the same question as [this one from yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33220424/3156750).

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing that out. You're right this is almost exactly the same problem. I have also found the description in the manual at section 4.5.3. and finally found the solution. Therefore, what I did is as follows: I check the value of st_value of each symbol. If its bit zero is set, then it addresses a thumb function therefore the address will be st_value-1 and disassembled in Thumb mode. Otherwise st_value will be the address of an ARM function and is disassembled in ARM mode.

Comment: Yup, it's basically the exact same logic as the CPUs use for interworking branches.